# Find the equilibrium temperature distribution on the region

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the spherically symmetric Heat equation :

$ \large \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{k}{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) \ $

Find the equilibrium temperature distribution on the region between two concentric spheres of radii $ r_1 \ $ and $ \ r_2 \ $ with $ r_2> r_1 \ $ with the given boundary conditions:

(i) $ u(r_1)=T_1 , \ u(r_2)=T_2 \ $

(ii) $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} (r_1)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r_2)=0 \ $

**Answer:**

For equilibrium solution, $ \ u \ $ must be independent of time $ t \ $

Hence $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0 \ $

Thus the equation becomes

$ \frac{\partial }{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} )=0 \\ u(r)=\frac{c_1}{r}+c_2 \ $

**Now how  can I apply the given boundary conditions ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: plug in your conditions and solve for the constants in terms of the given values

Answer (score 1):

Insert them in your generic solution, e.g. $u(r_1) = T_1$ and $u(r_1) = \frac{c_1}{r_1} + c_2$

Therefore $T_1 = \frac{c_1}{r_1} + c_2$.

You should be able to have $u$ be dependent of $T_1$ and $T_2$ instead of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

As for (ii) you might notice that even after applying the boundary condition you still have a whole class of solutions $[u] = u_0 + const$. That usually happens with Neumann BC, since you only have information about the derivatives.